# Regular expressions exclude search phrase?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I filter a string and search like
`/(?=test).*/s`

it works. but how can I exclude the search phrase from result? I want only the rest after this word...

Comment: You're gonna need to provide a search string example as well as what you're looking for specifically in it.

Comment: I search here for string "test" if you look into the expression. but I want to keep this phrase still in my string. I want to exclude only rest of the match

Comment: provide us a sample of the data you're actually searching. What I mean is give us a URL or whatever if is you're running that regex on.

Comment: You should use a lookbehind, not lookahead.

Comment: `(?=.*\btest\b.*).*(\btest\b).*` = `.*(\btest\b).*`. `(?=.*\btest\b.*)(?:.*)(\btest\b)(?:.*)` is even more inefficient. Please consider accepting a [more advanced solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603678/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that maybe an expression with word boundary might work:

```
(?=.*\btest\b.*).*(\btest\b).*
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/HzkCbG/1/)

we can also include non-capturing groups, for non-test parts:

```
(?=.*\btest\b.*)(?:.*)(\btest\b)(?:.*)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/pw938M/1/)

#### Example

```
$re = '/(?=.*\btest\b.*)(?:.*)(\btest\b)(?:.*)/m';
$str = 'test some other words that comes after
some other words before test some other words that comes after';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also get you match without a positive lookahead by matching the last occurrence of test and then forget what was matched using `\K`. You might also match following horizontal whitespace characters using `\h`.

```
^.*\btest\b\h*\K.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qLgIP7/1)

If you want to get the rest after the first occurrence of `test` you could make the dot non greedy `.*?`

Another option could be to split on `\btest\b` to get all the parts and select the ones you want to keep.